# connection of two .htaccess files

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, laravel

On my site is currently running wordpress so my .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

But I need to test other(laravel) application there. If I replace .htaccess with this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

my laravel app works. Is there any way how to be able to keep working both apps?
Specifically it would be good if second app runs just on some alias e.g. www.mysite.com/secreturl. I tried to combine it like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


RewriteRule ^secret(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

But I couldn't achieve anything. Thanks.

Comment: Run each in there own directory or sub domain

Comment: isn't there any way how to combine it? Running in own directory doesn't work, and subdomain would be my last chance because my hosting has a bit weird folder structure

Comment: your wordpress is in the `public_html` and laravel is in `public_html` as well with its public folder in `public_html/public`?

Comment: no, structure of my ftp is www->domains->xxx.com, so wp is in xxx.com, laravel is int in xxx.com/laravel and xxx.com/public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have both apps in the same directory, because they would both need `index.php` as the application entry point and that creates conflicts (also Laravel's `public` directory shouldn't be inside the document root, it should be the document root).

You should serve the Laravel application (if that's of secondary importance) using a virtual host either in a subdirectory or a subdomain. Here's an example using a subdomain:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName laravelapp.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/larvel/app/public"

    <Directory "/path/to/larvel/app/public">
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I don't have access to do anything like your example code. If I place laravel into subdirectory then routing is not working.

Comment: If you're using a shared server, create a subdomain with the aid of your control panel (that usually creates a subdirectory in your document root with the subdomain name). Move your Laravel application code to that subdirectory, then follow [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@kunalnagar/deploying-laravel-5-on-godaddy-shared-hosting-888ec96f64cd) on how to setup Laravel on a shared hosting (because shared hosting services often have limitations and Laravel was not designed for that). The tutorial is for GoDaddy, but you can extrapolate the necessary steps from that and use them on any hosting.

Comment: I have followed that tutorial. But it's just not working. Problem is that my hosting has structure like this: www/domains/xxx.com, www/subdom/name, and I have to have 1 .htacces inside www(to let the domains, aliases, subdomains working correctly). It was working just once when I replaced that wp .htaccess with mine(not in subdomain-it doesn't work there-  I am able to set up just homepage)